# How to sort an ArrayList of Doubles contained within a MultiValuedMap

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have a MultiValuedMap (Apache commons), with keys of String and values stored in an ArrayList of Doubles, read from a file. I don't need to sort the keys, but I do need to sort the ArrayList associated with each key. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried Collections.sort but that doesn't seem to work with the MultiValuedMap. I haven't tried creating a Comparator yet but I wasn't sure how to begin one for something inside a Map.

```
//Read file of data to be placed in MultiValuedMap 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String line = "";
String csvSplitBy = ",";


//Create the MultiValuedMap    
MultiValuedMap<String, Double> mvMap = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();

//Read data into MultiValuedMap
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       String[] cols = line.split(csvSplitBy);
       mvMap.put(cols[4], Double.parseDouble(cols[3]));  

//This gives an error
Collections.sort(mvMap);
```

The error I get from the Collections.sort is "no suitable method for sort(MultiValuedMap)"

I'm not looking to sort the keys, just the values. So an expected output should be something like:

44 => [284.5, 289.35, 300.53, 534.0] and
41 => [311.82, 368.45, 400.2]

Comment: As you said, you don't want to sort the map, and yet, that's what you're trying to do here: `Collections.sort(mvMap);`. What you want to sort is the list of values associated to a key of the map, so... that's what you need to sort: `Collections.sort(mvMap.get(someKey));`

Comment: Ah okay, I would have to do it per key? If there's a lot of keys, is there an efficient way of doing it to every key and arraylist value? I'm also apparently getting the same error even if I try a key ("No suitable method found for sort(Collection<Double>)"

Comment: Instead of storing doubles in an ArrayList<Double>, can you store them in TreeSet<Double>? If yes, then you don't need to do anything at all. Problem is already solved since TreeSet sorts the elements and Double already implements compare and compareTo methods.

Comment: I needed to use the MultiValuedMap since the file had duplicates values for each key. As far as I know a Set can't have duplicate values.

Comment: I see, but does mvMap.values().forEach(v -> v.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())); doesn't help?

Comment: I thought your data structure was MultiValuedMap<String, List<Double>> mvMap = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>(); or it should be

Comment: That doesn't work. I get an error "cannot find symbol, symbol: method sort(Comparator<T>). When constructing the MultiValuedMap, it creates an array of doubles out of the file values, so the declaration is <String, Double> but the output is <String, ArrayList<Double>>. At least, that's my understanding, and declaring mvMap as <String, ArrayList<Double>> causes errors with putting the values into the Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've tried all the suggestions (thank you!) but all have received some sort of error or another for incompatible types.

The only thing I could do is create a workaround and create a new regular HashMap and pull the ArrayList from mvMap into an ArrayList, sort it, and then put it into a new HashMap. This isn't super efficient but it's what I was able to come up with, and it works. If you have any other suggestions, though, please let me know and I will continue to try them. I appreciate the help!

Here's what I added:

```
//Declared with the other variables
HashMap<String, List<Double>> sortedMap = new HashMap<String, List<Double>>();

//Added after the while loop
for (String key : mvMap.keySet()) {
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>(mvMap.get(key));
    Collections.sort(list);
    sortedMap.put(key, list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.sort` expects a Collection that can be sorted. You're passing it a MultiValuedMap which can't be sorted. Instead what you need to do is call `Collections.sort` for each of the individual ArrayLists.

Something like this should work (I haven't seen the actual lib, but this is following map conventions)

```
for(String s: mvMap.keySet()){
    Collections.sort(mvMap.get(s));
}
```

That iterates through each strings and sorts it with the list given

Comment: Still getting errors. The first one gets "no suitable method found for sort(Double)" and the second "no suitable method found for sort(Collection<Double>)" which seems puzzling since get() should return a Collection (as per the documentation from Apache for MultiValuedMap).

Comment: @mxember I can't try it out and fiddle with it myself. But if you replace `Collections.sort(mvMap.get(s)` with `mvMap.get(s).sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(d -> d));` it'll work

Answer (score 0):

According to java docs `MultiValuedMap` implements `Map`'s get. So the compiler is assuming the type of value we get from `MultiValuedMap.get()`  is a `Double`

I would do a workaround for `Collections.sort(mvMap);` with something like

```
for (String key : mvMap.keySet()) 
    mvMap.put(key, Collections.sort((List<Double>)mvMap.get(key));
}
```